# Keras custom callback to save history dictionary and order of callbacks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to save the entire training history dictionary at each epoch. It seems the `keras.callbacks.History()` generates this dictionary in the `.history` object? I am writing a callback to save the dictionary to json at each epoch as follows;

```
class MyCallback(ks.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self,model_folder_path):
        self.model_folder_path = model_folder_path

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        this_path = os.path.join(self.model_folder_path,"History epoch {:02d}.json".format(epoch))
        with open(this_path, 'w') as fh:
            json.dump(self.model.history.history, fh)
        print("Saved history to {}".format(this_path))
```

And adding to my list of callbacks. When I run the training, each history object is missing the history of the current epoch - I assume this means the `keras.callbacks.History()` callback is being called after my callback, so that my callback is not seeing the current change. Is this correct? Can I specify that my callback goes last in the calling order? I tried `keras.callbacks.CSVLogger` in the meantime, but I would like to save the dictionary directly. I found a [stale issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2521) on GitHub - any other tips?

Comment: Having a similar when calling my custum callback, after `training model.history.history` is `{}`

Comment: However within the `on_train_end` function in my callback, `self.model.history.history` is definitely filled

Answer (score -1):

to save the history of your model to a file instead of using `json.dump` use

```
    with open('/path_to_your_history', 'wb') as file_pi:
        pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)
```

where history is the output of `model.fit()`

Comment: It's not the format that's the problem - it's the calling order of the methods.